# Sending a SIGIO signal to another process after sending to a message queue (C)

Tags: c, signals, message-queue

I'm writing an assignment where one process (the sender) is supposed to send messages to another process (the receiver) using a message queue. The assignment states that Receiver should not block or poll the queue, but rather Sender should SIGIO to the Receiver after sending a message to the queue.

My problem is that I do not know how to do this. I'm sure the problem isn't with the queue, but either the signal handler on Receiver's end or sending SIGIO on sender's end.

This is sender's code, which is called on a timer:

```
/*code for sending a message, works as intended*/
/*code below is questionable*/
//msqid is the message queue id; I'm guessing that's the file descriptor I want.
fcntl(msqid, F_SETOWN, receiver_pid); //designates receiver as the process to send the signal too?
int flags;
flags = fcntl(msqid, F_GETFL); //save flags
fcntl(msqid, F_SETFL, flags | O_ASYNC); //set flag that sends SIGIO?
```

This is the signal handler set up in the main function of receiver (the format is copied from an alarm handler that does work, so I think this is right):

```
struct sigaction act;
memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act)); //clear it
act.sa_handler = &packet_handler;
if (sigaction(SIGIO, &act, NULL) == -1)
{
perror("Error setting up SIGIO handler");
}
```

And finally the receiver calls pause() while it waits for messages.

```
  while (pkt_cnt < pkt_total) {
  pause(); /* block until next packet */
  }
```

The result when I run this code is that all the messages get put on the queue, but the signal handler in receiver never triggers.

How do I trigger the signal handler in Receiver based on the actions of Sender?

Comment: `man kill`: "kill - send a signal to a process..." ?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. In my searching I was hung up on using SIGIO which led to fcntl.